# Problem with Jquery

Tags: jquery

I am using a jquery to show fields of HTML like select,text, image. But my issue as I am involving it using for loop, if once I select 5 than I select 3 using dropdown than I wish rest two fields should be removed. Second my image field is showing as text field.

```
 <select id="prescriptionnum"  >
      <option value="">Select Number</option>
      <option value="1">1</option>
      <option value="2">2</option>
      <option value="3">3</option>
      <option value="4">4</option>
      <option value="5">5</option>
  </select>

$('#prescriptionnum').change(function() {
    var childid = $("#childprescriptionselect").val();
    var prescriptionnum = $("#prescriptionnum").val();
    $('#prescription').show("slow");
    for (var i = 0; i < prescriptionnum; ++i) {

        $("<select/>&nbsp",{class:"selectdoctor"}).appendTo("#prescriptionform");       
        $("<input/>",{type:"text",class:"textinput"}).appendTo("#prescriptionform");
        $("<input/>",{type:"file",class:"imageinput"}).appendTo("#prescriptionform");


   }
});
```

I need good formatting that is space and enter between fields.

http://jsfiddle.net/xDAmf/

Comment: There is no `#childprescriptionselect`, `#prescription` or `#prescriptionform`. Html missing?

Comment: Can you provide the whole code? (what's in `#prescriptionform`?)

Comment: updated the url http://jsfiddle.net/xDAmf/

Comment: They are the rest of html fields. I haven't described all here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the number of fields change, remove all items via:

```
$("#prescriptionform").children().remove();
```

Then add them back. You can use [`$.before()`](http://api.jquery.com/before/) and [`$.after()`](http://api.jquery.com/after/) to add additional markup such as `&nbsp;` or `<br/>`. [Demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/salman/xDAmf/6/).

Comment: Great its working good. How will I add id using loop. I mean for i=1 i want id as selectdoctor1

Comment: Y u have removed this. `$("#prescriptionform").children().remove();`

Comment: Yes, Parvesh's suggestion about using `.empty()` is better.

Comment: I am  having text field at place of button. Suppose if I print button using jquery it will show me textfield. and I can input in that. Though its working fine in jsfiddle

Answer (score 2):

you can empty the prescription form before filling in it with html controls

```
$('#prescriptionnum').change(function() {
var childid = $("#childprescriptionselect").val();
var prescriptionnum = $("#prescriptionnum").val();
$('#prescription').show("slow");

//make the form empty before putting in contols
$("#prescriptionform").empty();
for (var i = 0; i < prescriptionnum; ++i) {

    $("<select/>&nbsp",{class:"selectdoctor"}).appendTo("#prescriptionform");       
    $("<input/>",{type:"text",class:"textinput"}).appendTo("#prescriptionform");
    $("<input/>",{type:"file",class:"imageinput"}).appendTo("#prescriptionform");


   }
});
```

Comment: my button are showing as text field. I mean instead of browse I am getting text field to input.

Comment: try  $("<input type='file' class='imageinput'/>").appendTo("#prescriptionform");